# Windows Command Line- Assign High Priority to FINDSTR within a loop

Tags: command-line, cmd, findstr

Does anybody know how to manipulate this code so that the FINDSTR process always is assigned high priority?

```
FORFILES /P C:\path /M * /C "cmd /c FINDSTR /c:"@FILE"   C:\path\*">C:\path\repgenresults.txt
```

I tried assigning priority manually in Task Manager, but I would need to do that a couple thousand times, because each new process with a new iteration of the loop is assigned normal priority. I also tried combining the cmd and start functions without much luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You could put everything inside a batch file then use the command START to execute the batch file with the priority choosen

[See START references](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html)

Example

```
START "RunAsHighPriority" /HIGH /WAIT YourCommand.cmd
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work exactly as I was hoping it would. It started the command itself with high priority, but the programs FORFILES.exe and FINDSTR.exe, which the command launches, still run with normal priority. Any advice on how to get these programs within the command to always run with high priority? Thanks

Comment: A possible workaround could be `cmd /c start /HIGH /WAIT batchfile.cmd`, but I have not tested. Let me know.

Comment: Just tested it, and the same problem occured. Would there maybe be a way for, within the loop, the command to start a new FINDSTR.exe process with each iteration? Just a shot in the dark. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Sorry, but the last option will be to write a dedicated program. Doesn't seem very complex and if it's a business critical function could also be a cost/effective way to solve.

Comment: EDIT: I tried to make the FINDSTR a seperate .cmd file, and start it with a high priority with each iteration of the loop, but they all ran extremely quickly and crashed the system. Any workaround for that?