# How to increase process priority with python

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I am working with application written in python on windows 7, it needs calling process and setting the priority of the process to high, how can I increment or change the called process priority with python?

Comment: Is the parent process running as administrator?

Comment: yes it is running as administrator

Comment: Why would being admin matter? And why are you running admin anyway?

Comment: Related: [Start child process with limited priority](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13799371/95735)

Comment: I don't know if it matter or not, but the process is running admin because it need to access many critical resources

Comment: related: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761057/windows-command-line-assign-high-priority-to-findstr-within-a-loop](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10761057/4279). You could use with `subprocess` module if you can't install `psutil` module that provides a more uniform api (`.nice`)